# signed apk from git shared source is crashing on bogus claims of missing classes

Tags: android, git, apk

I am working on an android project. The project is shared through git. Each time I need to create a signed apk it's a hassle. The apk gets created but when I try to use the app, some file is always missing. Then I try disconnecting my local copy from the git sharing, then reconnecting, then rebasing, etc. Then it would create a good apk that works with no crash for supposed missing classes. (Note: the classes aren't really missing. They are classes I personally create inside the project)

My problem is, every time I need to create a signed apk, I have to emotionally gear up for a battle. And I have not figured out a repeatable process that is guaranteed to give me a good apk.

I only have this problem when exporting a signed apk. If I simply connect the device and build the code, that version of the app works. But that is not an exported apk, as it is using the debug key.

Does anyone know how to get exported apk to work with my git setup?

**MORE DETAILS:**

I am using

- ADT eclipse
- Egit

Comment: What is so special about your git setup? Can you provide your app's architecture?

Comment: There is nothing special about my git setup. That's my point. It's just a basic android project that I am sharing using git. But it seems that git or Egit is interfering with the process of exporting a signed apk.

Comment: @J.Romero I have edited to mention ADT eclipse and Egit. I think they aren't playing well with each other.

Comment: Try to uninstalling EGit and see if that works properly. EGit has proven to be so buggy for me that I only use cli now. Not saying that it's the problem but worth trying.

Comment: Thanks. That's actually what I have been trying to do. But uninstalling a plugin from ADT is not straightforward. So my other question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261213/how-to-uninstall-plugin-egit-from-adt-eclipse