# how to uninstall plugin/egit from ADT eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, adt

I found these instructions

> You should not remove plug-ins from Eclipse. Plug-ins should be
>   installed as features using the Update Manager. The same Update
>   Manager can be used to disable plug-ins by disabling the feature they
>   belong to. Run Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details, select the
>   software you no longer want and click Uninstall. (On Macintosh it is
>   Eclipse > About Eclipse > Installation Details.) In older versions,
>   you might need to Run Help > Software Updates > Manage
>   Configuration..., select the feature of interest, and disable it with
>   the task shown in the right window.

But they are not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

From ADT, go to Help > Install New Software... Then click on the link "What is already installed". You will have the list of your plugins and an uninstall button at the bottom.

Comment: For me, the uninstall buttons are disabled. They are all under an **eclipse** folder and I only have the option to uninstall Eclipse.